# is destination alarm or notification alert possible in leaflet

Tags: dictionary, leaflet, alarm

**Want to setup destination alarm in leaflet map**

i developed leaflet map with mapzen. also i successfully implement routing and bookmarks on specific locations with *leaflet* and *mapzen* its work fine.

now i want to make an **alarm system** so that user can add alarm with a form showing him add destination and so he can add a marker on the map or can add lon and lat of location. so when user in real time reaches that location alarm should ring on that location.

GPS tracking already working fine for me i used leaflet routing machine plugin

i created map with metro extracts of mapzen

for geocoding i used leaflet geocoding plugin

**what i have already done?**
*sound Notification on coordinates on leaflet map*

then i used QGIS for styling 
then i used leaflet for making it web map.
[map with routing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wwbnk.png)
then i used leaflet routing machine plugin for routing
now every thing is good till this point
[currentmap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NoAnq.png)

**What i want?**

now i want to add an alarm so that user can add alarm from form on specific location so in real time when user reached that location alarm should ring. so for this i need help and guidance.

Leaflet destination alarm
custom notification alarm
map alarm system on coordinates
please help me how can i add alarm in my app
thanks

Comment: You sound to describe a "geofencing" functionality. Should be quite simple to perform. Every time your current location changes, compare its distance to your destination. Trigger something if that distance is below a chosen threshold. You could do something similar with any shape, not just point and distance.

Comment: thanks for your response i will try and if need will request you further help

Comment: i searched and found that it is possible to add destination alarm. now my problem is that i want users to add alarm via form in front end so user can add destination and tone for alarm. any help in this regard appreciated as it will save lot of my time thanks

Comment: The easiest way to save your time is to pay for another developer's time.

Comment: Please how are you going to convince people to freely spend their _own_ time and help you with such attitude?

Comment: i think i ask about just hint or tip i didnot ask any one to give me app with out my efforts. any how i already done that thanks for your help